# How do I know the duration of a sound in Web Audio API

Tags: audio, web-audio-api

It's basically all in the title, how do I know or how can I access the duration of a `soundNode` in Web Audio API. I was expecting something like `source.buffer.size` or `source.buffer.duration` to be available.

The only alternative I can think of in case this is not possible to accomplish is to read the file metadata.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you are loading audio, when you decode it with context.decodeAudioData the resulting arrayBuffer has a .duration property.  This would be the same arraybuffer you use to create the source node.

You can look at the [SoundJS implementation](https://github.com/CreateJS/SoundJS/blob/master/src/soundjs/WebAudioPlugin.js), although there are easier to follow tutorials out there too.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Good and bad news; nodes do not have length - but I bet you can achieve what you want another way.

Audio nodes are sound processors or generators. The duration of a sound processed or made by a node can change - to the computer it is all the same, lack of sound is a buffer full of zeroes instead of other values.

So, if you needed to dynamically determine the duration of a sound,  you could write a node which timed 'silences' in the input audio it received.

However I suspect from your mentioning of meta data that you are loading existing sounds - in which case you should indeed use their meta data, or determine the length by loading into an audio element and requesting the length from that.